# reload tableview on click of picker element with updated data in titanium

Tags: javascript, uitableview, titanium-mobile, titanium-android

I have a json response like this which is coming from API call.

```
`{
"id": "7",
"issue_title": "Apr - May 2015",
"issue_no": "Issue 1.4",
"cover_image_url": "http://www.link.org/apr--may-2015-7.jpg",
"synopsis_pdf_url": "",
"advertisers_pdf_url": "",
"issue_date": "01-04-2015",
"issue_year": "2015" 
},
{
"id": "3",
"issue_title": "Feb-Mar 2015",
"issue_no": "Issue 1.3",
"cover_image_url": "http://www.link.org/febmar-2015-3.jpg",
"synopsis_pdf_url": "http://www.link.org/febmar-2015-3.pdf",
"advertisers_pdf_url": "http://www.link.org/febmar-2015-3.pdf",
"issue_date": "01-02-2015",
"issue_year": "2015"
},
{
"id": "2",
"issue_title": "Dec 2014 - Jan 2015",
"issue_no": "Issue 1.2",
"cover_image_url": "http://www.link.org/dec-2014--jan-2015-2.jpg",
"synopsis_pdf_url": "",
"advertisers_pdf_url": "",
"issue_date": "01-12-2014",
"issue_year": "2014"
},
{
"id": "1",
"issue_title": "Oct - Nov 2014",
"issue_no": "Issue 1.1",
"cover_image_url": "http://www.link.org/oct--nov-2014-1.jpg",
"synopsis_pdf_url": "",
"advertisers_pdf_url": "",
"issue_date": "01-10-2014",
"issue_year": "2014"
}`
```

Now I am retreiving `issue_year` which I am displaying in picker.

I want if a user clicks on `issue_year` the table data should display only records which have same `issue_year`.
Like if 2014 is clicked from picker it should display only 3rd and 4th record.
Now from controller I am passing object which jsonResponse[i] in the picker when picker data is prepared so as to retreive the same in its click but I am getting `undefined`.

js code is as follows

```
function openpastIssues(e) {

var url = "http://example.com/api/past_year_issue.aspx";
var jsonResponse;
var response;

var data = [];
var pickerData = [];
var singleData = [];
var row;
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function() {
        // parse the retrieved data, turning it into a JavaScript object
        Ti.API.info("From Past Issues (function): " + this.responseText);
        jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        var rowHeight = 150;
        // just pick the right height here
        var imageRowIsFull = false;
        var myImage;
        var issuelbl;

        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
            height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
            layout : "horizontal"
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {
            var tView = Ti.UI.createView({
                width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
                height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
                left : "5%",
                right : "5%",
                top : "5",
                bottom : "5",
                backgroundColor : "#A9F5A9",
                //backgroundColor : "black",
                layout : "vertical"

            });

            issuelbl = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                color : 'blue',
                text : jsonResponse[i].issue_title,

                height : "auto",
                width : "auto",
                left : "3%",
                font : {
                    fontSize : 13
                },
            });

            tView.add(issuelbl);

            myImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                width : 120,
                //left : "5%",
                //right : "5%",
                top : "5",
                //bottom:"5",
                height : 150,
                image : jsonResponse[i].cover_image_url,
                obj : jsonResponse[i]
            });
            tView.add(myImage);
            try {
                myImage.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    Ti.API.info('Clicked data = ' + JSON.stringify(e.source.obj));
                    var jsonRes = e.source.obj;
                    Alloy.createController('singleissue', jsonRes);
                });
            } catch(e) {

            }
            row.add(tView);
            //row.add(myImage);
            imageRowIsFull = false;

            if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0) {//this will add a new row every 2 items.
                imageRowIsFull = true;
                data.push(row);
                row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                    width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
                    height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
                    layout : "horizontal",
                    filterCriteria :jsonResponse[i].issue_year

                });
            }
            pickerData[i] = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
            title : jsonResponse[i].issue_year,
            obj : jsonResponse[i]
            });

        }

        if (!imageRowIsFull) {//do not forget to add the last row
            data.push(row);
        }



        //table.setData(data); 
        $.issueTable.setData(data);
        $.picker.add(pickerData);

    },

    onerror : function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert('error');
    },
    timeout : 5000
});

xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
}
$.picker.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
Ti.API.info('From picker ' + e.source.obj);
});
```

xml file

```
<Alloy>
<Window id="winpast" class="container" title="Past issues" onOpen="openpastIssues">
    <View id="view2"  width="Ti.UI.FILL" height="Ti.UI.FILL" backgroundColor="#A9F5A9" >
        <View id="viewcheck1" >
            <Label id="title" width="Ti.UI.SIZE" text="Past Issues" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" textAlign="Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER"></Label>
            <ImageView id="menuImg" image="/images/menu.png" onClick="showsideBar" left="5"></ImageView>
            <Picker id="picker"  selectionIndicator="true" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="Ti.UI.SIZE" right="10">

            </Picker>
        </View>
        <View id="tablePast" width="Ti.UI.FILL" height="Ti.UI.FILL" top="40">
            <TableView id="issueTable" scrollable="true"></TableView>
        </View>
        <View id="viewBelow" width="150" height="Ti.UI.FILL" backgroundColor="#A9A5A9" left="-150" visible="false" top="40">
            <TableView id="menuTable"></TableView>
        </View>

    </View>
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

Basically I want to display a records of particular year selected from picker.

Can anyone please help on this.
I have spent a lot of time on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an NSMUtableArray and repopulate it depending on the values of "issue_year". You can use NSPredicate for sorting through your json

Comment: I forgot to mention the platform.I am using Titanium platform.Just updated my question title.sorry for that.